# jQuery 1.5.1 stopping a function working... any ideas?

Tags: jquery

Peoples,

I recently moved from 1.4.1 to 1.5.1 to make use of a few updates, but it has stopped some functions working for some reason.

The function below take in a confirm button (x) as a parameter and checks to see if all input fields that are not optional have something in them.

If everything is fine, it continues, if there is an error, it shouldn't allow you to close the box until you complete the necessary data.

```
function checkAllInputs(x){
        var missingRequired = x.closest('.container').find('input[value=""]').not('.jsOptional');
        if (missingRequired.length) {
            // DO NOT CLOSE THE BOX
        }
        else {
            x.closest('.container').hide();
            // CLOSE THE BOX and continue
        }
    };
```

At the moment however - regardless of missing inputs, the button still closes the box.

Any ideas, or is there any more info needed?

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Do you have a javascript debugger? Which method is returning unexpected results? Without HTML to view, the question is hard to answer.

Comment: Could you make a simple test case - possibly on [Web Devout](http://www.webdevout.net/test)?

Comment: Other good online web dev demo tools: http://jsfiddle.net and http://jsbin.com

Answer (score 2):

I can duplicate the problem by testing with a simple form which has only text inputs (for simplicity). When I add the `:text` pseudo selector, or the `[type=text]` attribute filter, it works fine. Example:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    var missingRequired = $(this).find('input:text[value=""]').not('.jsOptional');
    alert(missingRequired.length);
    if (missingRequired.length) {
        alert(missingRequired.length);
        alert("missing!");
    }
    else {
        alert("none missing!");
    }
    return false;
});
```

Test markup:

```
<form>
    <input class="jsOptional" type="text"/>
    <br />
    <input type="text" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

[**You can try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/H4vPt/2/) (remove `:text` and it will break, test it out :)

I would suggest the following more robust approach to determining which inputs have been left empty:

```
var missingRequired = $(this).find('input:text')
                             .not('.jsOptional')
    .filter(function() {
       return $.trim($(this).val()) == ""; 
    });
if (missingRequired.length) {
    ...
```

The problem seems to relate to failing to specify the type of input - that said, it could be many other things, it's hard to know without seeing your markup. I guess I'm just bored.